# when on click try to create subweb, it gives me error

Tags: sandbox-solution

This function works fine,

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', loadCurrentWeb);
```

but when I put it in,

```
function AddNewSubWebNow() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', loadCurrentWeb);
}
```

it gives me,

> Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is '0'.
>   The status text of response is ''.

Comment: it was because i had button in my div, changed it to input fixed it